# Using SenTest to test an assertion

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, testing, assert

I have code in method which asserts( ) that a parameter falls within a given range. I'd like to test illegal parameters using a SenTest test case.

My first assumption was that I should use STAssertThrows( ... ) however this reports no exception is thrown when the assert fails. Can I catch assert() fails with an STAssert... macro?

[updated to provide an example]

In class Foo.m

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    NSUInteger count;
    NSUInteger max;
}
@end

@implementation Foo
-(void) bar:(char) c {
    assert( count < max );
    ...
}
@end
```

In class TestFoo.m

```
@interface TestFoo : SenTestCase {
    Foo testFoo_;
}
@end

@implementation TestFoo
    -(void) testBar {
        STAssertXXX( YYY );
    }
@end
```

What XXX and YYY can I use to test the failure or otherwise of the assertion in method bar: ?

Comment: Perhaps we could help you easier if you showed us an example of an assertion you are trying to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `NSAssert` (or `NSAssert1`, `NSAssert2`, etc.) instead of `assert`, you can catch an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch `assert` because it is not an obj-c exception. To fix this, just declare your own macro `MY_ASSERT(condition)` which will throw an exception if the condition is not met and use it instead of standard `assert`.